# How to read directory and all files inside in Python

Tags: python

I am still new to python and I am making a simples application which is to extract text from ppt files.

I have this project structure.

```
> Project_Python
    >> Files
       >>> Class A
             - History.ppt
       >>> Class B
             - Animals.ppt
    >> Result
            ???
 - main.py
```

My question is how can I read the files inside sub_folder of `Class A` and `Class B?`
And I want it to automatically create the folder structure of `Files` inside `Result` after print

This is what i've tried

```
from pptx import Presentation
import glob
import pathlib
import os

p_temp = pathlib.Path('Files') //How can I read sub folders folder dynamically

for eachfile in glob.glob("**/*.pptx"):
    prs = Presentation(eachfile)
    print(eachfile)
    print("----------------------")
    textdata = []
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if hasattr(shape, "text"):
                textdata.append(shape.text)
    print(''.join(textdata[1:]) , file=open("Result/"+eachfile+".txt" , "a")) //Create the same folder structure of Files
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct except usage of glob.glob.
You should also pass **recursive=True** parameter

To create directory with subdirs you can use **os.makedirs**

```
from pptx import Presentation
import glob
import pathlib
import os

p_temp = pathlib.Path('Files') //How can I read sub folders folder dynamically

for eachfile in glob.glob(p_temp+"**/*.pptx", recursive=True):
    prs = Presentation(eachfile)
    print(eachfile)
    print("----------------------")
    textdata = []
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if hasattr(shape, "text"):
                textdata.append(shape.text)
    os.makedirs(str(pathlib.Path(eachfile).parent).replace('Files','Result')
    print(''.join(textdata[1:]) , file=open("Result/"+eachfile+".txt" , "a")) //Create the same folder structure of Files
```

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this helpful answer, now read files on sub categories. But my one main concern is the makedir, still does not create own folder same with files.

Comment: Result folder structure has Class A and Class B folder inside.

Comment: but the creating of folder should be dynamic not by manual. How can i do it

Comment: How about this dirty hack:   __os.makedirs(str(pathlib.Path(eachfile ).parent).replace('Files','Result'))__. Another way is to extract Class from path with regular expression